# Nextjs 13 with Sequelize (App router) just hangs on model query

Tags: postgresql, next.js, sequelize.js

Does anybody have any code to reference to add the Sequelize ORM to a Nextjs 13 project with a postgres dialect? I see a lot of references with Next 12 or lower, but nothing with Next 13, specifically accessing the Sequelize connection inside a route.ts file. When querying the db using a sequelize method (EX [modelName].findAll()), it just hangs... Spent hours trying to solve the problem and no luck!

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Sequelize instance:

```
// lib/db.js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
});

export default sequelize;
```

Use the Sequelize instance in your route:

```
// pages/api/route.ts
import db from '../../lib/db';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const posts = await db.models.Post.findAll();
  res.json(posts);
}
```